# Docker set limit (restrict, fix) image version tag to pull (FROM) only one concrete major release version number

Tags: image, docker, updates, semantic-versioning

How to write a FROM statement in the Dockerfile that pulls the latest image from a specific Major version. 
Let's say there is an application that currently has three major versions: v1.7, v2.5, v3.0.5 and I want to have always the latest version of image v2. if i put in the Dockerfile statement:

```
FROM imagename:latest
```

Then I'll get build version 3.0.5 because it is the latest version. If I put:

```
FROM imagename:2.5
```

Then I'll get exact version 2.5 but will not be able to update the image with this statement once the version 2.6 becomes available.

How to set FROM statement that will get always the latest version 2 updates that will not brake backwards compatibility and stick to that major version 2.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker image tags (including both the Dockerfile `FROM` line and `docker run` images) are always exact matches.  As a corollary, once Docker believes it has a particular image locally, it won't try to fetch it again unless explicitly instructed to.

Many common Docker images have a convention of publishing the same image under multiple tags, that sort of reflect what you're suggesting.  For instance, as of this writing, for the [standard `python` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/python/), `python:latest`, `python:3`, `python:3.7`, `python:3.7.0`, and `python:3.7.0-stretch` all point at the same image.  If you said `FROM python:3` you'd get this image.  But, if you already had that image, and a Python 3.8 were released, and you rebuilt without explicitly doing a `docker pull` first, you'd use the same image you already had (the Python 3.7 one).  If you did `docker pull python:3` then you'd get the updated image but you'd have to know to do that (or tell your CI tool to do it for you).

Comment: so there is no way from my side to implement the latest major version no x? It all depends on the publisher of the image if they provide some general label like phyton:2 then I'll get always the latest version of 2nd Major, and if they only provide concrete version numbers like 2.3, 3.5 etc then I'm not able to get the latest version of major 2 unless I edit the Dockerfile or change the number in command line?

Comment: No: you can't pattern match, and in general there's no way to list tags of an image.

Comment: it's a pity, I'm totally depended on an image publisher in this matter but good to know so in case I release my image to public I'll take care for proper tag labels, also more generic ones like `phyton:3` that reflect latest version of a particular major ver.